# Adding value to "li" in html and using it in JS as a variable that applies only to the specific li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I'm using the YouTube API to autoplay videos as a sequence using the video id and now I need to also add starting and ending times that differ according to the specific video.

Here is a couple `<li>` that I have in my HTML where "id" is the actual "id of YouTube video":

```
<li data-pile="pile1" id="CH7ysrZXDSw" class="md-trigger md-setperspective" data-modal="modal-1">
      <img src="../images/video-thumbnail1.png" alt=""/>
/li>
<li data-pile="pile1" id="kQKhpVWBjoQ" class="md-trigger md-setperspective" data-modal="modal-1">
      <img src="../images/video-thumbnail2.png" alt=""/>
</li>
```

Here is the section of the JS where I have hard coded starting and ending times:

```
function playVideo(videoId, cb) {
    if(videoId) {
        myModal.find('.md-video').append($videoDiv);
        myModal.addClass('md-show');
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('#### id', videoId);
            player.loadVideoById({'videoId': videoId, 'startSeconds': 40, 'endSeconds': 60});
            player.videoEnded = function () {
                cb && cb();
            };

            player.waitForChanges();
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

What I need:

1) I need to include in my HTML the information for the starting and the ending time of videos.

2) Get that information of the videos from HTML and use it in JS as a variable instead of being hard coded on JS as: `...player.loadVideoById({'videoId': videoId, 'startSeconds': 40, 'endSeconds': 60});`

Comment: [YouTube API v2.0 – Retrieving Data for a Single Video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries)

Comment: I don't think this is about the api since I have it working already. I just need to add values in my html list and use them in JS as a variable.

Comment: Can you put them in `data-` attributes in the `li` tags?

Answer (score 1):

Put them in `data-` attributes in the li tags or add them as classes.